# Problemas con la ejecución de mi aplicación Ionic en Vercel

Tags: json, vercel

Mi aplicación Ionic, alojada en Vercel, compila correctamente, pero no funciona. Al acceder al enlace generado, se muestra una página en blanco y solo carga el icono de la URL. Mi archivo vercel.json es el siguiente:

```
vercel.json
{
  "version": 2,
  "name": "proyecto",
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "/package.json",
      "use": "@vercel/static-build",
      "config": {
        "outputDirectory": "dist/repo"
      }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.\.(css|js|jpg|png|svg|ico|woff|woff2))$",
      "dest": "/dist/repo/$1"
    },
    {
      "src": "/(assets/.)",
      "dest": "/dist/repo/$1"
    },
    {
      "src": "/.*",
      "dest": "/dist/repo/www/index.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.